# Placing towers issue (TDS) - Roblox Studio

Tags: roblox

The problem at hand is i am able to select towers and place towers with my cursor, but attempting to restrict placements unable to place on a path, instead of grass. Towers stay Red and Unable to place.

Currently no Coding Errors. I dont understand the issue.

```
local PhysicsService = game:GetService("PhysicsService")
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local RunService = game:GetService("RunService")
local UserInputService = game:GetService("UserInputService")

local events = ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("Events")
local towers = ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("Towers")
local spawnTowerEvent = events:WaitForChild("SpawnTower")
local camera = workspace.CurrentCamera
local gui = script.Parent

local towerToSpawn = nil
local canPlace = false

local function MouseRaycast(blacklist)
    local mousePosition = UserInputService:GetMouseLocation()
    local mouseRay = camera:ViewportPointToRay(mousePosition.X, mousePosition.Y)
    local raycastParams = RaycastParams.new()

    raycastParams.FilterType = Enum.RaycastFilterType.Blacklist
    raycastParams.FilterDescendantsInstances = blacklist

    local raycastResult = workspace:Raycast(mouseRay.Origin, mouseRay.Direction * 1000, raycastParams)

    return raycastResult
end

local function RemovePlaceholderTower()
    if towerToSpawn then
        towerToSpawn:Destroy()
        towerToSpawn = nil
    end
end

local function AddPlaceholderTower(Name)
    local towerExists = towers:FindFirstChild(Name) 
    if towerExists then
        RemovePlaceholderTower()
        towerToSpawn = towerExists:Clone()
        towerToSpawn.Parent = workspace.Towers

        for i, object in ipairs(towerToSpawn:GetDescendants()) do
            if object:IsA("BasePart") then
                PhysicsService:SetPartCollisionGroup(object, "Tower")
                object.Material = Enum.Material.ForceField
            end
        end
    end 
end 

local function ColorPlaceholderTower(color)
    for i, object in ipairs(towerToSpawn:GetDescendants()) do
        if object:IsA("BasePart") then
            object.Color = color
        end
    end
end

gui.Spawn.Activated:Connect(function()
    AddPlaceholderTower("SwordsMan")
end)

UserInputService.InputBegan:Connect(function(input, processed)
    if processed then
        return
    end

    if towerToSpawn then
        if input.UserInputType == Enum.UserInputType.MouseButton1 then
            if canPlace then
                spawnTowerEvent:FireServer(towerToSpawn.Name, towerToSpawn.PrimaryPart.CFrame)
                RemovePlaceholderTower()
            end
        end
    end

end)    

RunService.RenderStepped:Connect(function()
    if towerToSpawn then
        local result = MouseRaycast({towerToSpawn})
        if result and result.Instance then
            if result.Instance.Parent.Name == "TowerArea" then
                canPlace = true
                ColorPlaceholderTower(Color3.new(0,1,0))
            else
                canPlace = false
                ColorPlaceholderTower(Color3.new(1,0,0))
            end
            local x = result.Position.X
            local y = result.Position.Y + towerToSpawn.Humanoid.HipHeight + (towerToSpawn.HumanoidRootPart.Size.Y / 2)
            local z = result.Position.Z

            local cframe = CFrame.new(x,y,z)
            towerToSpawn:SetPrimaryPartCFrame(cframe)

        end
    end
end)
```

Switching some Variables, paths... no avail.